# Unique key with Empty values

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, jpa

This is the schema for the table, here defined a unique constraint with job_category_id, screening_type_id, test_id, sex.

```
CREATE TABLE job_profile
(
  profile_id numeric(5,0) NOT NULL,
  job_category_id numeric(5,0),
  test_id numeric(5,0),
  sex character(1),
  default_yn character(1),
  screening_type_id numeric(5,0),
  CONSTRAINT job_profile_pkey PRIMARY KEY (profile_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_jobprofile_jobcate FOREIGN KEY (job_category_id)
      REFERENCES job_category_mast (job_category_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_jobprofile_test FOREIGN KEY (test_id)
      REFERENCES test_mast (test_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_prof_screentype FOREIGN KEY (screening_type_id)
      REFERENCES screening_type_mast (screening_type_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT uk_job_test_sex_screening UNIQUE (job_category_id, screening_type_id, test_id, sex)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE job_profile
  OWNER TO cdcis;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE job_profile TO cdcis;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE job_profile TO cdcis_app;
```

If one field is empty then the unique constraint fails here.

[image]

How to add constraint so that one empty value is accepted, so it will be unique.

Can handle this scenario in the application using JPA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/indexes-unique.html):

> Null values are not considered equal

So unique constraint won't work this way.
You have 2 options:

1. Create a trigger that will manually check the data integrity and deny changes if the table contains more than one empty value.
2. Set default value to `0` and `NOT NULL` constraint on these columns. In that case, you will be able to have only one row containing empty (zero) value.

---

Update:

As [Abelisto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593144/abelisto) suggested, it can be easily done with [functional indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html).

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uix_job_test_sex_screening on job_profile(coalesce(job_category_id, -1), screening_type_id, test_id, sex);
```

Comment: I guess putting a dummy value like `0` won't work as there won't be a corresponding job_category for that value

Comment: @user630209 3. Create unique functional index instead of constraint like `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uix_job_test_sex_screening on job_profile(coalesce(job_category_id, -1), screening_type_id, test_id, sex);`

Comment: @Abelisto that's a perfect solution. I never used functional indexes before.

Comment: Which is better, handle this in db level or application level ?

Comment: @Abelisto, Do we need to use coalesce in this ?

Comment: @user630209 Surely, it is the main part of the solution. Probably you should to use `coalesce` for other fields also depending on your task.

Comment: @user630209 it's up to you. But handling this at DB level is easier and more solid solution.

Comment: @Abelisto Can some one explain this  " coalesce(job_category_id, -1) ", tried searching didn't got exact answer for this

Comment: @user630209 [coalesce](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL). So index will use not exactly fields values but fields values except `NULL`s which will be converted to the value provided by `coalesce` function (-1 in our example).